# Classes that reference each other in F#

Tags: f#

I have two classes defined like so:

```
type foo () =
    let getBar() = 
        new bar()

type bar () =
    let getFoo() = 
        new foo()
```

The compiler is saying

```
The type 'bar' is not defined
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this is where the `and` keyword is used (have to be in the same file obvious):

```
type Foo () =
   let getBar () =
      Bar ()

and Bar () =
   let getFoo () =
      Foo ()
```

#### remark

you can use this too if you have mutual recursive functions (or even values) - but there you have to add the `rec` keyword to the first binding:

```
let rec f x = if x > 0 then g x else 0
and g x = f (x-1)
```

Comment: no problem - btw: I did not mention it but you don't have to add `new` in F# when you create objects - indeed it idiomatic to only use `new` if the object implements `IDisposable` (and the compiler will even warn you if you don't use it in this cases)

Comment: PS: and of course types should begin with a captial Letter ;)